# Form elements are being ignored when submitting and serializing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

Right now I'm trying to create a sort of test form in HTML, and certain elements are being ignored both when submitting the form and using serializeArray(). The basic form code looks like this:

```
<form action="/form-submit" method="POST">
  <div id="login">
    <h1>Form Title</h1>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></input><br>
    <label>Key:</label>
    <input type="text" name="key" id="key"></input><br>
    <button onclick="hideLogin()" type="button" class="next-section" id="start-test" disabled>Start Test</button>
    <p id="invalid-key">Invalid Key</p>
  </div>
  <div id="earth">
    <p>Earth questions</p> 
  </div>
  <div id="bio">
    <p>Bio questions</p>
  </div>
  <div id="chem">
    <p>Chem questions</p>
  </div>
  <div id="physics">
    <p>Physics questions</p>
  </div>
  <div id="math">
    <p>Math questions</p> 
  </div>
  <div id="end-page">
    <p>end page</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

The questions are added from a questions object like so:

```
function readQuestions(section){
  questions[section].forEach((item, number) => {
    if (item.type === "mc") {
      $(`#${section}`).append($(`<div id="${section}-${number}"></div>`))
      $(`#${section}-${number}`).append(`<label class="mc-question">${item.question}</label>`)
      $(`#${section}-${number}`).append(`<ul></ul>`)
      item.choices.forEach((choice,index)=>{
        $(`#${section}-${number} ul`).append('<li></li>').append(`<label class="container" for="${section}-q${number}-c${index}">${choice}<input type="radio" name="${section}-q${number}" id="${section}-q${number}-c${index}"><span class="checkmark"></span></label>`)
      })
    } else {
      $(`#${section}`).append($(`<div id="${section}-${number}"></div>`))
      $(`#${section}-${number}`).append(`<label for="${section}-q${number}" class="short-question">${item.question}</label>`)
      $(`#${section}-${number}`).append(`<input type="text" id="${section}-q${number}" name="${section}-q${number}">`)
    }
  })
  if (section === 'math') {
    $(`#math`).append($(`<input type="submit" class="next-section" disabled>Submit Test</input>`))
  } else {
    $(`#${section}`).append($(`<button onclick="nextSection('${section}')" type="button" class="next-section" disabled>Next Section</button>`))
  }
}
```

The sections are invisible using `visibility: hidden` and `position: absolute` until the user gets to that section, when they are made visible and position is set to static. Right now, the two inputs for name and key in login section are always visible when the form is submitted, but none of the other elements. When `console.dir()`ing the serializeArray() once per section of the form when each is visible, it shows name, key, and the questions for that section, but none of the questions from earlier or later sections. Is there a reason why some of the inputs would be excluded like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a different piece of code, I disabled the inputs after the timer for each section ran out. Disabled inputs are not submitted with the form or read by serializeArray(), so instead I had to make the inputs readonly. Making them readonly also disables user input but includes them in both the form submit and serializeArray().